# Jquery drag and drop is slow for few android devices

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ionic-framework

I am new in programming.I am using jquery ui drag and drop with ionic for puzzle .For few devices dragging is very smooth but for few it's very slow .Can anyone suggest me that is there anything for jquery ui drag with smooth touch.Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the what is the issue that its run smooth in some devices and not on some. but its better that you won't use j-Query in your application instead use this [plugin](http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#!/) developed in the AngularJS which is also easily integrate with ionic